# mex.h header bugs in Vivado HLS {array of pointers}

Tags: c, vivado, vivado-hls

This is my mex function. Bugs were found with mxArray because of open arrays []. Is there a solution to counter this ?

I've attached only the code but nevertheless the recurring problem is with mxArray's and extern bool.

Code:

```
/*
 * @(#)mex.h    generated by: makeheader    Mon Sep  4 03:57:16 2000
 *
 *      built from: ../include/copyright.h
 *              mex_typedefs.h
 *              fmexapi.c
 *              globals.c
 *              mexapi.c
 *              mexapiv4.c
 *              mexcbk.c
 *              mexintrf.c
 *              modver/modver.c
 */

#ifndef mex_h
#define mex_h


/* $Revision: 1.3 $ */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1984-2000 The MathWorks, Inc.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 */



/* $Revision: 1.4 $ */
#ifndef mex_typedefs_h
#define mex_typedefs_h
typedef struct impl_info_tag *MEX_impl_info;

#include "matrix.h"

typedef struct mexGlobalTableEntry_Tag
{
    const char *name;             /* The name of the global */
    mxArray    **variable;        /* A pointer to the variable */ 
} mexGlobalTableEntry, *mexGlobalTable;

typedef struct mexFunctionTableEntry_tag {
  const char *  name;
  mxFunctionPtr f;
  int           nargin;
  int           nargout;
  struct _mexLocalFunctionTable *local_function_table;
} mexFunctionTableEntry, *mexFunctionTable;

typedef struct _mexLocalFunctionTable {
  size_t           length;
  mexFunctionTable entries;
} _mexLocalFunctionTable, *mexLocalFunctionTable;

typedef struct {
  void (*initialize)(void);
  void (*terminate)(void);
} _mexInitTermTableEntry, *mexInitTermTableEntry;

#define MEX_INFORMATION_VERSION 1

typedef struct {
  int                   version;
  int                   file_function_table_length;
  mexFunctionTable      file_function_table;
  int                   global_variable_table_length;
  mexGlobalTable        global_variable_table;
  int                   npaths;
  const char **         paths;
  int                   init_term_table_length;
  mexInitTermTableEntry init_term_table;
} _mex_information, *mex_information;

typedef mex_information(*fn_mex_file)(void);

typedef void (*fn_clean_up_after_error)(void);
typedef const char *(*fn_simple_function_to_string)(mxFunctionPtr f);

typedef fn_clean_up_after_error fn_mex_enter_mex_library;
typedef fn_clean_up_after_error fn_mex_exit_mex_library;

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif


/*
 * This header file "mex.h" declares all the types, macros and
 * functions necessary to interface mex files with the current
 * version of MATLAB.  See the release notes for information on 
 * supporting syntax from earlier versions.
 */  
#include "matrix.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(applec)
/* MATLAB is compiled with Metrowerks CodeWarrior C.  
   File I/O functions in MPW SC MEX-files are mapped back to MATLAB
   to avoid Data-to-Code Reference link errors from IntEnv.o.
   So, the macros defined in SC's stdio.h which make direct reference
   to the elements of a FILE structure need to be redefined as 
   callbacks to MATLAB.
 */
#undef getc
#undef putc
#undef clearerr
#undef feof
#undef ferror
#endif



/*
 * mexFunction is the user defined C routine which is called upon invocation
 * of a mex function.
 */
void mexFunction(
    int           nlhs,           /* number of expected outputs */
    mxArray       *plhs[],        /* array of pointers to output arguments */
    int           nrhs,           /* number of inputs */
#if !defined(V4_COMPAT)
    const mxArray *prhs[]         /* array of pointers to input arguments */
#else
    mxArray *prhs[]         /* array of pointers to input arguments */
#endif
);

#if defined (powerc) && defined(__MWERKS__) && defined(MATLAB_MEX_FILE)
#pragma export list mexFunction
#endif


/*
 * Issue error message and return to MATLAB prompt
 */
extern void mexErrMsgTxt(
    const char  *error_msg  /* string with error message */
    );


/*
 * Issue error message if warnings enabled in MATLAB
 */
extern void mexWarnMsgTxt(
    const char  *error_msg  /* string with error message */
    );


/*
 * mex equivalent to MATLAB's "disp" function
 */
extern int mexPrintf(
    const char  *fmt,   /* printf style format */
    ...             /* any additional arguments */
    );


/*
#define printf mexPrintf
*/


/*
 * Remove all components of an array plus the array header itself
 * from MATLAB's memory allocation list.  The array will now
 * persist between calls to the mex function.  To destroy this
 * array, you will need to explicitly call mxDestroyArray().
 */
extern void mexMakeArrayPersistent(
    mxArray *pa              /* pointer to array */
    );


/*
 * Remove memory previously allocated via mxCalloc from MATLAB's
 * memory allocation list.  To free this memory, you will need to
 * explicitly call mxFree().
 */
extern void mexMakeMemoryPersistent(void *ptr);


/*
 * Look up a function and return an opaque handle for use with
 * mexCallMATLABFunction.
 */
extern void mexGetFunctionHandle(void);


/*
 * Call a function whose handle was determined by mexGetFunctionHandle.
 */
extern void mexCallMATLABFunction(void);


/*
 * Register a function pointer as a MATLAB-callable function.
 */
extern void mexRegisterFunction(void);


/*
 * mex equivalent to MATLAB's "set" function
 */
extern int mexSet(double handle, const char *property, mxArray *value);


/* API interface which mimics the "get" function */
extern const mxArray *mexGet(double handle, const char *property);


/*
 * call MATLAB function
 */
extern int mexCallMATLAB(
    int     nlhs,           /* number of expected outputs */
    mxArray *plhs[],        /* pointer array to outputs */
    int     nrhs,           /* number of inputs */
    mxArray *prhs[],        /* pointer array to inputs */
    const char  *fcn_name       /* name of function to execute */
    );


/*
 * set or clear mexCallMATLAB trap flag (if set then an error in  
 * mexCallMATLAB is caught and mexCallMATLAB will return a status value, 
 * if not set an error will cause control to revert to MATLAB)
 */
extern void mexSetTrapFlag(int flag);


/*
 * Perform in-place subscript assignment.
 */
extern void mexSubsAssign(
      mxArray *plhs, /* pointer to lhs, to be modified in-place */
      const mxArray *sub[], /* array of subscripts for lhs */
      int nsubs,     /* number os subscripts */
      const mxArray *prhs /* pointer to rhs */
      );


/*
 * Retrieve a specified subset of an array.
 */
extern mxArray *mexSubsReference(
      const mxArray *prhs, /* pointer to rhs */
      const mxArray *subs[], /* array of subscripts for rhs */
    int nsubs /* number of subscripts */
      );


#endif /* mex_h */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't know the size yet of the arrays you can use double pointers and allocate them where needed.

```
mxArray **plhs;
```

What you have is an incomplete type in a struct and after that a complete type.

Like this is not allowed:

```
struct {
    char *x[];
    int y;
};
```

But this is as you can specify the size at the declaration point:

```
struct {
    int y;
    char *x[];
};
```

Comment: Even after using double pointers, 'mxArray' could not be resolved.

Comment: oh is that the problem.....next time say what the error message is. you have to include the header where mxArray is declared or put struct in front of every mxArray and include it in the c file where you must know the size of an mxArray

Comment: Thanks Servé, it helped me. Also, i'm wondering why unit32_t cannot be resolved. Can i use struct there as well ?

Comment: uint32_t can be found in stdint.h